# Using "->" in c#?

Tags: c#, syntax

I have remembered that I have seen "->" used in C#. Apparently I cannot search it through Google (and I do not know what is the name). Therefore I would be very happy if you could explain it to me.
Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Are you sure you mean -> and not => ?

Comment: Wasn't it "-->" that you've seen?

Comment: Why not put that as the answer, Charlie? :)

Comment: @GMan Because I don't know much about the operator and he asked for it to be explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ofcourse it is used ..

 the operator -> is used to access the members of a struct (its a pointer).

MSDN Site would be better for seeking information on VB, C# and etc ..
[here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 19):

`->` Accesses a member of a struct through a pointer.

See [-> Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h%28VS.71%29.aspx)

and

[Pointer Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx)

```
using System;
struct Point
{
   public int x, y; 
}

class Test 
{
   public unsafe static void Main() 
   {
      Point pt = new Point();
      Point* pp = &pt;
      pp->x = 123;
      pp->y = 456;
      Console.WriteLine ( "{0} {1}", pt.x, pt.y );
   }
}
```

Outputs

```
123 456
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`->` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h.aspx) is used for dereferencing pointers, and is used only in unsafe C# code.

Pointers are more or less like object references, except that they point to a memory address. It's a little closer to the internal workings of the system, but it puts garbage collection and type safety out of play. References are more abstract and more restrictive, but allow the runtime to guarantee type safety and do memory management.

See also this MSDN article about unsafe code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)?

Comment: wj32: Yeah, hence the reason my post started with "Do you mean ...".

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h.aspx)

> The `->` operator combines pointer dereferencing and member access

Answer (score 1):

It's used the same way it's used in C - to access a field in a struct using a pointer. To use pointers in C#, you need to have `/unsafe` enabled. For example:

```
unsafe
{
    MyStruct* ptr;

    Console.WriteLine(ptr->SomeField.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an operator that is not commonly used, only in unsafe code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h(VS.80).aspx

Comment: unsafe code is a language feature of C#. What does make its usage un-normal, then?

Comment: Johannes: What? Are you normally writing lots of unsafe functions, then? If so, good for you, but it's not *normal*, in general c# code.

Comment: Unsafe code makes the code unverifiable and works against .NET concepts as garbage collection etc..

It is mostly used for calling native APIs.

Comment: silky: No, I don't. But I'd consider `unsafe` to be no less normal than lambdas or LINQ. el.pescado suggests a nice alternative :-)

Comment: Johannes: Maybe it's a language thing; in English it is quite acceptable to use "normally" in the fashion above.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same as in C++. But to have pointers in C# requires "unsafe" code and you don't want to do that too much...

```
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 5;
        int* p = &x;

        Console.WriteLine(p->ToString());
    }
```